# What's the correct update syntax in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting the database sqlite exception with my update syntax. Where do I place the quotes to not get the error "no such column"?

```
    //2.create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("active", _active); //update active flag

    //3.updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_NAME,//table
            values,//column/value
            COLUMN_UID+"="+_uid,//selections
            new String[]{String.valueOf(_uid)});//selectionargs
```

My code produces this error. I know a quote should be surround the _uid variable but that doesn't seem correct either.

> 2019-08-12 21:39:19.620 22215-22215/com.bab_c.picksandbets
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.bab_c.picksandbets, PID: 22215
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bobbyb2222 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pab_pref SET active=?
>   WHERE uid=bobbyb2222

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotes around the variable, only use a placeholder for the parameter:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("active", _active); 
int i = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_UID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(_uid)});
```

This is the recommended way for updating.
Don't use other ways like directly passing the variable surrounded by quotes, because this may cause [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).